# ValueError: putmask: mask and data must be the same size

Tags: python, pandas, valueerror

I have a pandas dataframe and I wanted to replace its index values using the `where()` method, but I got the following error.

> ValueError: putmask: mask and data must be the same size

How do I solve this error?

Steps to reproduce the error:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [1, 3, 5]})
df.index.where(lambda x: x>0, 10)      # ValueError: putmask: mask and data must be the same size
```

In the above example, I expect to replace index=0 by index=10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike `Series.where`, [`Index.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.where.html) does not work on callables, so using a `lambda` function to mask values would not work. You must pass a boolean array/Series/list with the same length as the original index.

So any of the following works.

```py
df.index.where(df.index > 0, 10)                # #1
df.index.where([False, True, True], 10)         # #2
df.index.to_series().where(lambda x: x>0, 10)   # #3
```

If you pass a boolean array-like that does not have the same length, you will get the same error:

```py
df.index.where([True, True])               # <--- ValueError: putmask: mask and data must be the same size
df.index.where([True, True, True, False])  # <--- ValueError: putmask: mask and data must be the same size
```

---

If you want to mask a pandas Index object in a chained way, then converting to series might be easier. For example, the following is a case where only datetime values after 2020 are shown.

```py
(
    pd.date_range('2020', '2023', freq='250D')
    .to_series()
    .where(lambda x: x.dt.year > 2020)
)
```

The same result may be obtained in two lines as follows:

```py
dt = pd.date_range('2020', '2023', freq='250D')
dt = dt.where(dt.year > 2020)
```